# How to do redirect in actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript

When in `page.html?xxx` which embed `1.swf`,how can I redirect to `page.html?xxx&new_param=1` (preserving original parameters,append a new parameter `new_param=1`)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the same url parameters that were passed to the html page, not the swf, then call out to JavaScript using `ExternalInterface` to do the redirect.

Alternatively you can pass the full url to the swf via flashvars and redirect with `flash.net.navigateToURL()`.